# How do I confirm deselection of a value in a multiple select field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say that I have a multiple select field like this:

```
<select id="foodlist" multiple="multiple">
 <option selected="selected" value="59">Apple</option>
 <option value="61">Orange</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="1">Goat</option>
 <option value="2">Chicken</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="46">Rice</option>
</select>
```

When an option is selected, no prompt should be given. However, if an option is deselected, I want the user to `Confirm` their deselection. I started implementing this using jQuery in the `change` function like this:

```
$("#foodlist").change(function () {
  //check to see if we are selecting or deselecting an option
  //I only want to do the next step if we are deselecting an option
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to remove: " + $(this).text() + "?")) {
        //re-select the option that was deselected because the user changed their mind
    }
});
```

My main problem is that the `$(this)` selector in the change function refers to the entire list when I really want the item that was **clicked** so that I can see if it was selected/deselected and get the value. Is there a jQuery selector for this? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to attach a `click` event handler on `option` element and then check if it is selected or not. Try this

```
$("#foodlist option").click(function () {
   if(!$(this).is(':selected')){
      if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to remove: " + $(this).text() + "?")) {
          //re-select the option that was deselected 
          //because the user changed their mind

          $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
   }
});
```

**Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xurrx/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass an Event to your change function like this

```
$('#foodlist').change(function(e){
   //e.originalTarget();
   console.debug(e);
})
```

I'm not sure if this also works with the `.change()` but it sure does with `.click()`. I recommend you to use Firebug and simply do a `console.debug(e);`. So you can view the Event and it's properties. So normaly you can see under originalTarget or just Target, which HTML Element has been clicked. But be aware that **.originalTarget(); doesnt work in IE** ! So I would recommend you to simply use `.target();`

Probably you could save all the "States" of your options in an array when the .change() method is called. But before you do that you simply go through your Select again and compare the actual status of the options (which means if they are selected or not at the moment) with the "last" status.
So everytime you call the .change() Function you compare whether any option has been selected oder deselected and if someone got deselected you do your alert().

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use

```
$("#foodlist").change(function (event) {
  //check to see if we are selecting or deselecting an option
  //I only want to do the next step if we are deselecting an option
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to remove: " + event.currentTarget.text() + "?")) {
        //re-select the option that was deselected because the user changed their mind
    }
});
```

Comment: close. I get the SelectElement but I get a js error saying that `Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'text()'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#foodlist").find('option').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':selected')){
        console.log('selected');
    }else{
        console.log('not selected');
    }
});
```

Check out the working demo!

http://jsfiddle.net/DJfjq/2/

Hope this helps